# how to get the value of a particular child node element using the other child node as a reference

Tags: xml, xmlreader

I am looking for an end string which will contain the values of the parent node way 'id' value followed by the 'ref' value of the child node nd and then the values of k='ele' and v='0'  i.e something like

```
id=1000000000;ref= 1000000000,1000000001,1000000002, 1000000003; k = ele and v =0;
```

I need to update the elevation v= 0 in an existing database based on the values of elements id,ref and ele of the parent 'way' and children 'nd' and 'tag' nodes using xmlreader class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <osm version="0.5" generator="Srtm2Osm">
<node id="1000000000" lat="51.5254166666667" lon="13.73375" />
<node id="1000000001" lat="51.52625" lon="13.7345833333333" />
<node id="1000000002" lat="51.5254166666667" lon="13.7354166666667" />
<node id="1000000003" lat="51.5245833333333" lon="13.7345833333333" />
<way id="1000000000">
    <nd ref="1000000000" />
    <nd ref="1000000001" />
    <nd ref="1000000002" />
    <nd ref="1000000003" />
    <nd ref="1000000000" />
    <tag k="ele" v="0" />
    <tag k="contour" v="elevation" />
    <tag k="contour_ext" v="elevation_major" />
</way>
```

Comment: I need the string to update v= 0, elevation in a database but it should correspond with the way 'id' value, nd 'ref' value and k= ele value of tag. Any suggestions please

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result you are expecting....

Comment: I have created a database in postgresql and already imported the data node id , lat and lon , now I need to update the correponding elevation data v.  This link has the xml file for sachsen which is in particular [http://geoweb.hft-stuttgart.de/SRTM/srtm_as_osm/Lat51Lon13Lat52Lon14.osm.zip]

Comment: I need the output to be for example id 1000000000,ref 1000000000 1000000001 1000000002 1000000003,k ele v 0; for the above snippet , in the string obtained so that I can update the correct elevation value for the correct lat and lon values correspondingly

Comment: just a part of the code may be this will help you understand what I am trying to do @Monty